# JQ write each object to subdirectory file

Tags: json, file, jq

I'm new to [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) (around 24 hours). I'm getting the filtering/selection already, but I'm wondering about advanced I/O features. Let's say I have an existing jq query that works fine, producing a stream (not a list) of objects. That is, if I pipe them to a file, it produces:

```json
{
  "id": "foo"
  "value": "123"
}
{
  "id": "bar"
  "value": "456"
}
```

Is there some fancy expression I can add to my jq query to output each object individually in a subdirectory, keyed by the `id`, in the form `id/id.json`? For example `current-directory/foo/foo.json` and `current-directory/bar/bar.json`?

Comment: No, `jq` doesn't provide that level of I/O features. You will have to do it from the shell. But you can make `jq` help you with it. For instance, you could use the `-c` flag to output each object on a separate line which facilitates the handling from the shell. Also, you could additionally streamline the extraction of the parts you need for file and folder names. There is no canonical solution to that, and you will have to leave `jq` to accomplish it.

Answer (score 0):

As @pmf has pointed out, an "only-jq" solution is not possible.  A solution using jq and awk is as follows, though it is far from robust:

```
<input.json jq -rc '.id, .' | awk '
  id=="" {id=$0; next;}
  { path=id; gsub(/[/]/, "_", path);
    system("mkdir -p " path);
    print >> path "/" id ".json";
    id="";
  }
'
```

Answer (score 0):

As you will need help from outside `jq` anyway (see [@peak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73409957/2158479) using `awk`), you also might want to consider using another JSON processor instead which offers more I/O features. One that comes to my mind is [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq), a `jq`-inspired processor for YAML, JSON, and other formats. It can [split documents into multiple files](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/usage/split-into-multiple-files), and since its [v4.27.2 release](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/releases/tag/v4.27.2) it also supports reading multiple JSON documents from a single input source.

```bash
$ yq -p=json -o=json input.json -s '.id'

$ cat foo.json
{
  "id": "foo",
  "value": "123"
}

$ cat bar.json
{
  "id": "bar",
  "value": "456"
}
```

The argument following `-s` defines the evaluation filter for each output file's name, `.id` in this case (the `.json` suffix is added automatically), and can be manipulated to further needs, e.g. `-s '"file_with_id_" + .id'`. However, adding slashes will not result in subdirectories being created, so this (from here on comparatively easy) part will be left over for post-processing in the shell.